# How to find min/max aggregations with diffrerent filters in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation, nosql-aggregation

Considering collection `clothing` of documents with this strucure

```
{
  "brand": <string>,
  "color": <string>,
  "size": <number>
}
```

In a single aggregation grouing by `brand` I would like to find two values:

1. min size for all documents in a group where `color="blue"`
2. max size for all documents in a group where `color="red"`

In SQL it would be something like this:

```
SELECT MIN(CASE color WHEN "blue" THEN size ELSE NULL END),
       MAX(CASE color WHEN "red" THEN size ELSE NULL END),
       brand
  FROM clothing
 GROUP BY brand
```

How to express this in MongoDB query?

Answer (score 1):

The answer above yields `null` for min when only a single data observation is present; it should show the same value for both `max` and `min`.  Here are some alternatives.   The first is the simple one that directly answers the OP question -- but it is noticeably "hardcoded" for color:

```js
db.foo.aggregate([
    {$group: {_id: '$brand',
              'red_max': {$max: {$cond: [{$eq:['$color','red']}, '$size', 0]}},
              'red_min': {$min: {$cond: [{$eq:['$color','red']}, '$size', 99999999]}},
              'blue_max': {$max: {$cond: [{$eq:['$color','blue']}, '$size', 0]}},
              'blue_min': {$min: {$cond: [{$eq:['$color','blue']}, '$size', 99999999]}}
             }
    }
]);
```

The second solution is more exciting as it will produce `max` and `min` for *all* colors encountered.

```js
db.foo.aggregate([
    {$group: {_id: {c:'$color',b:'$brand'}, max:{$max: "$size"}, min:{$min: "$size"}}}
    // Arguably, you are done by the stage above -- but to make the output more 
    // convenient, employ a "regroup" stage to move the material around:
    ,{$group: {_id: '$_id.b', data: {$push: {color: '$_id.c', max: '$max', min: '$min'}}}}
    ,{$unwind: "$data"}  // optional, really...                                                            
]);
```

You can easily capture just red and blue by performing a `$match` before the `$group`, or to get everything else as "OTHER" besides the target red and blue, change the first `$group` stage to:

```js
    {$group: {_id: {c:{$cond:[{$in:['$color',['red','blue']]},'$color',"OTHER"]},  b:'$brand'},
              max:{$max: "$size"}, min:{$min: "$size"}}}
```

Lastly, there may be times when in addition to finding the max and min, we wish to know about other fields in the same doc as the max and min.  This is possible with a slightly more complex query:

```js
db.foo.aggregate([
    {$group: {_id: {c:'$color',b:'$brand'}, XX:{$push: "$$CURRENT"}}}

    ,{$addFields: {XX: {$reduce: {
        input: "$XX",
        initialValue: {max:{size:0}, min:{size:99999999}},
            in: {
                max: {$cond: [{$gt:['$$this.size','$$value.max.size']},'$$this','$$value.max']},
                min: {$cond: [{$lt:['$$this.size','$$value.min.size']},'$$this','$$value.min']}
            }
    }}
    }}

    ,{$group: {_id: '$_id.b', data: {$push: {color: '$_id.c', max: '$XX.max', min: '$XX.min'}} }}
]);
```

Yes, you do end up with repeated/redundant data in the `max` and `min` objects (specifically `brand` and `color`) but all other peer fields will be carried over without having to change the query, e.g.:

```js
{
    "_id" : "B2",
    "data" : [
        {
            "color" : "red",
            "max" : {
                "_id" : 13,
                "brand" : "B2",
                "color" : "red",
                "size" : 8,
                "o1" : "A14",
                "o2" : [
                    "P",
                    "Q"
                ]
            },
            "min" : {
                "_id" : 8,
                "brand" : "B2",
                "color" : "red",
                "size" : 6,
                "o1" : "A9",
                "o2" : [
                    "K",
                    "L"
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "color" : "blue",
            "max" : {
                "_id" : 9,
                "brand" : "B2",
                "color" : "blue",
                "size" : 7,
                "o1" : "A10",
                "o2" : [
                    "L",
                    "M"
                ]
            },
            "min" : {
                "_id" : 9,
                "brand" : "B2",
                "color" : "blue",
                "size" : 7,
                "o1" : "A10",
                "o2" : [
                    "L",
                    "M"
                ]
            }
        },
...
```

If the redundant data is unacceptable, then you can use the `objectToArray-filter-arrayToObject` pattern to remove `color` and `brand`:

```js
    {$group: {_id: {c:'$color',b:'$brand'}, XX:{$push:
                   // "$$CURRENT"                        
                   {$arrayToObject: {$filter: {input: {$objectToArray: "$$CURRENT"},
                                               cond: {$not:{$in:['$$this.k', ['brand','color']]}}
                   }}}
    }}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "color": { "$in": [ "red", "blue" ] }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$color",
      "max": { "$max": "$size" },
      "min": { "$min": "$size" }
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LXEic4Pl9Aj)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. And sorry for setting my question not clear enough (updated it). I meant how to do this aggregation when grouping is by some other field, i.e. 'brand'.

Answer (score 0):

1. `$group` - Group by `brand` and `$push` `size` into `red` or `blue` array by `$cond`.
2. `$project` - Decorate output document with `$min` (blue) and `$max` (red).

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$brand",
      "red": {
        $push: {
          $cond: [
            {
              $eq: [
                "$color",
                "red"
              ]
            },
            "$$ROOT.size",
            "$$REMOVE"
          ]
        }
      },
      "blue": {
        $push: {
          $cond: [
            {
              $eq: [
                "$color",
                "blue"
              ]
            },
            "$$ROOT.size",
            "$$REMOVE"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      brand: "$brand",
      min: {
        $min: "$blue"
      },
      max: {
        $max: "$red"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4o_gaWkdIJf)

Answer (score 0):

Query

- `$min`,`$max` works on documents also, comparing fields in order
- "blue" is smaller than "red" so we dont need any extra step
  (if this was not the case you could say if blue => 1 else 0 to change the order, like assign a number to the possible strings, and have that number in the place of `$color`)

[Test code here](https://cmql.org/play/?q=71060226-m)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$group":
  {"_id":"$brand",
   "min-blue":{"$min":{"color":"$color", "size":"$size"}},
   "max-red":{"$max":{"color":"$color", "size":"$size"}}}}])
```